# change back iso file's default open program in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, iso-image

In Windows 10, I can use explorer to open iso file. I think windows 7 can also do it.

So I change an iso file default open program to `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`, but it didn't work, and I can't change it back.

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543602/how-to-change-default-program-open-rar-file-which-select-open-file-by-explorer), but after I change it, the `.iso` extension disappears from the list.

I tried the [registry](https://www.itechtics.com/set-default-apps/), change `Windows.IsoFile` entry's `shell->open` value, and rebooted, but it didn't work too

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the `UserChoice` subitem of .iso in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`, and it works now.

It has a `Progid` value, with `Application\explorer.exe` value, which is my previous selection. But I can't change it. So I deleted it.

After deletion, it automatically get a new value, which is `Windows.IsoFile`

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924822/16484529